# App Egine use JS Ajax and jinja to have dynamic dropdown

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm working on Google App Engine. I have a HTML file with some dropdown, I also use Jinja in there. 
An example :

```
 <form action="/quest4" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <select name="competition_name" id="competition_name" >
               <option value = "">Toutes les Compétition</option>
               {% for competition in CompetitionInData %}
               <option value="{{ competition.name }}">{{ competition.name }}</option>
               {% endfor %}
            </select>
         </form>
```

I use python to work on the server side. I would like to have two or more "cascade dropdown" I mean when a user chose something in the first dropdown, it lanchs a search in the datastore and then it fills the second dropdown without reloading the page.

I succed to have the begining : when a user chose something in the first dropdown, it lanchs a python function on the server side, I have the data I want from the datastore (a list of three words) and now I would like this three words to be in the second dropdown...

How can I do it ?

To make the user chose in the dropdown and launch a python function I used this code :

```
<script>
function showHint(str) {
     if (str.length == 0) { 
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
         return;
     } else {
         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
             }
         }
         xmlhttp.open("POST","/test123",true);
         xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         xmlhttp.send(str);
     }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form>
    <select name="day" id="day" onchange="showHint(this.value)">
        <option value = "">Toutes les journées</option>
               {% for day in day_int_sorted %}
               <option value="{{ day }}">{{ day}}</option>
               {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>

<div id="txtHint">
[ImHERE]
</div>
```

The div with the id "textHint" is filled with the answer of the python (as a string) when I choose something in the dropdown. The problem is that's a string and I cant get it or use it with some jinja intération (I would like to do something like that : {% for element in response %}) with response filled by the python function)

I don't know if the explanation of my problem is clear. Someone can help me ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Jinja is used for server-side templating.  Javascript can be used for handling the data returned from AJAX requests (typically as JSON) and dynamically add it to your page.

If you definitely need to use Jinja, you can change your python handler that your AJAX request is calling to use a Jinja template and return an html snippet instead of your data string.  You will still need javascript to place that snippet into your page.